Training a deep learning classifier on a mix of features from noise and the source of interest
I'm working on classification problem where features are sparsely observed e.g. only 60% of features are observed (out of ~500,000 features). Some of the observed features are from a source of noise (say 70% of observed features is noise), the rest is of interest for classification.
The positions that are observed from the noise source or the source of interest are completely random. I have some example samples of the background noise.
My current approach is to train a fully connected feed forward network on simulated samples that follow these rules. This seems to work reasonably well. Would there be a better solution e.g. filtering the signal of interest in some way to train a better classifier?
